# autoconf: should I always use AS_IF over if and m4_if?

Tags: shell, autoconf, m4

The autoconf manual suggest using `AS_IF` instead of `if`, but it doesn't mention `m4_if`. Should `AS_IF` also be preferred over `m4_if`?

The ["Limitations of Builtins"](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#if) section of the manual says to use `AS_IF` for it's portability, but the [`AC_REQUIRE` description](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Prerequisite-Macros.html) says to use it to expand required macros.

Should I always use `AS_IF`? The answer seems to be yes, but then again I see `if` and `m4_if` being used in other macros. When is it ok not to use `AS_IF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was confused about this because I didn't realize the fundamental difference between `if`/`AS_IF` and `m4_if`. The normal `if` and `AS_IF` have their conditionals evaluated when the user runs the script, i.e. `configure`. Conversely, `m4_if` has its conditional evaluated during macro expansion, i.e. `autoreconf`.

`if`/`AS_IF` affects the flow of the script. `m4_if` affects the contents of the script.

This seems obvious now, but I didn't get it at first. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: That doesn't say when to use `if` and when `AS_IF`.

Comment: I think the consensus is to always use `AS_IF` over `if`, because you get better quoting, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The other benefit of AS_IF is that when it expands, any macros that are required by macros in the branches are expanded before the test.

See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Common-Shell-Constructs.html).